# Apple Mail: Reply to my own sent e-mail, send to original recipient

Tags: mail.app, catalina

In Apple Mail, if I send a reply to an e-mail I’ve received, my sent e-mail shows up at the top of the conversation. If I then later on send a reply to my own sent e-mail, it used to be, in previous iterations of Apple Mail, that the app would figure out that I didn’t want to send an e-mail to myself, but rather a follow-up to the recipient of the original e-mail.

This seems to have changed for me in Catalina (currently on Mail version 13.4) so that I now find myself often accidentally sending myself e-mails that the intended recipients never receive (until I discover my mistake and rectify it). I can’t find a setting or any other way to get it back the way it used to be.

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352114/) from February 2019 seems to describe the same issue, with the exception that the poster was on Mojave and doesn’t seem to be describe a change in behaviour (it also doesn’t have any answers). Interestingly, at least one commenter mentioned the app working as intended (version 12.2), which agrees with my experience – that’s how it used to work.

Was this a deliberate change in Catalina (or Mail 13, perhaps)? Or is it a random bug? And in either case, **is there a way to fix it**?

Comment: iOS 13 also has this crazy behavior. It's nonsensical to first present messages as a *conversation* only to expose a reply button that replies to oneself.